# Question on environmental variable

Tags: environment-variables, java, etc

I have Oracle jdk7 installed on my centos6. I noticed that the /etc/profile has the lines below:

```
#below lines are added for Java
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/latest"
## export JAVA_HOME JDK ##
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75"
```

In order to test my assumptions on env variables and PATHs, I commented all the lines above (the export lines). I tried to load the new `/etc/profile` by sourcing it `. /etc/profile` and issued the `echo $JAVA_HOME`; it still returned the above path.

So, I rebooted the machine as the source didn't work. After the reboot, the `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns nothing, which is expected. There is nothing in `~/.bash_profile` for Java.

But if I issue the command:  `java -version` on the shell, it still returns

```
[root@localhost ~]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Where is the Java defined in the PATH? the path in the `~/.bash_profile` is as below, it doesn't have any for Java.

# User specific environment and startup programs

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
~
~
~
```

`set` - on the shell returns the line below for the PATH variable:

```
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: `java` is probably a script, you can find out by `which java`, then file `/usr/wahterver/java`. I'll bet for either `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` which must be in you $PATH.

Comment: @Archemar : indeed, it was there in /usr/bin/java ... when i installed the oracle jdk, it was installed in /usr/java/.. then i followed some instructions to set the desired oracle jdk instead of the open jdk. i am going to revisit the proceedure that might have set the /usr/java to /usr/bin/java.. Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't think you need to change the PATH. If you can run `java -version` it means that `java` is already in the PATH. All you have to do is set the variable JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `PATH` is set in `/etc/profile`. Users can modify their `PATH` by editing `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (if they're running `bash`) but if they don't they will still have a `PATH` as defined in `/etc/profile`. That's why the line was

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

and not just

```
PATH=$HOME/bin
```

That way, the original value of `PATH` is kept and the new directory is simply appended. On my system, the `PATH` set in `/etc/profile` is

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
```

You probably have a very similar line in yours and *that's* where `/usr/bin` comes from.